# Whould someone explain procstat output memory information?

Tags: process, freebsd, memory, proc

I use the command `procstat -r $(pidof myprocess)` and I get the following output...

```
  PID COMM             RESOURCE                          VALUE
84867 myprocess       user time                    00:00:12.637834
84867 myprocess       system time                  00:00:06.671334
84867 myprocess       maximum RSS                            11400 KB
84867 myprocess       integral shared memory               1931920 KB
84867 myprocess       integral unshared data                 28272 KB
84867 myprocess       integral unshared stack               301568 KB
84867 myprocess       page reclaims                            653
84867 myprocess       page faults                                0
...
```

I am kind of concerned about the huge values of

```
84867 myprocess       integral shared memory             1 931 920 KB
84867 myprocess       integral unshared data                28 272 KB
84867 myprocess       integral unshared stack              301 568 KB
```

**What do these three terms mean?**

`htop` gives me decent values about memory (VIRT, etc).
Should I concern about memory leaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is poorly documented, and confused me also.

The `integral shared memory`, `integral unshared data` and `integral unshared stack` status are running counters, not a current snapshot of usage.  It is normal for them to increase indefinitely.  They don't indicate a memory leak.

See http://www.khmere.com/freebsd_book/html/ch07.html for exact descriptions of each fields data.

Answer (score 2):

The `integral shared memory` includes the `code` and `rodata` segments of every shared library your program is linked against.  That nearly 2GB figure is large, but not totally surprising if it is a big app like a browser.  The unshared segments are data that was allocated by your program, including r/w data pages from shared libraries, etc.  If these aren't going up alarmingly (or worse, unbounded) you're probably OK.